# What is the purpose of the square root in Cohen's w?

Tags: effect-size

What is the purpose of the square root in Cohen's w, a measure of effect size used when analysing contingency tables? Here is the formula:

$w = \sqrt{\sum_{\text{cells}} \frac{(\text{obs. rel. freq.}-\text{exp. rel. freq.})^2}{\text{exp. rel. freq.}}}$

Answer (score 4):

This a question of convenience and consistency with other effect sizes, as correctly suspected in the other answer and its [comment section](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299749/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-square-root-in-cohens-w#comment570056_299773).

In the original edition of his book on power analysis (1969), Jacob Cohen originally used the effect size $e$ for chi-squared tests, such as:

$e = \sum_{\text{cells}} \frac{(\text{obs. rel. freq.}-\text{exp. rel. freq.})^2}{\text{exp. rel. freq.}}$.

He changed it for $\omega = \sqrt{e} $ in the revised edition (1977), which he briefly justified in the preface for reasons of convenience and consistency:

> The effect size index used for chi-square tests on frequencies and
> proportions (Chapter 7) has been changed from $e$ to $\omega$ ($
>  =\sqrt{e}$). This change was made in order to provide a more useful range of values and to make the operational definitions of "small,"
> "medium," and "large" effect sizes for tests of contingency tables and
> goodness of fit consistent with those for other statistical tests (particularly those of Chapters 5 and 6). The formulas have
> been changed accordingly and the 84 look-up tables for power and sample size have been recomputed.

If you have access to the second edition (1988), you can read it page xvii.

The effect sizes he mentions chapters 5 and 6 are Cohen's $g$ and [Cohen's $h$](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cohen%27s_h&oldid=1125508394), which are respectively used for the sign test and for differences between two proportions.

You could also use Cohen's $\omega$ as an effect size for these two scenarios. This is why he mentions the effect sizes $g$ and $h$, as well as the issue of their comparability to $\omega$ (e.g. one "small effect size" according to his benchark is when $\omega = 0.1$, $h = 0.2$ or $g = 0.05$).

---

However, one thing he doesn't seem to mention explicitly (unless I missed it) is that there is a perfect linear relationship between $\omega$ and $\lvert  g \rvert$, and under certain conditions an almost perfect linear relationship between $\omega$ and $\lvert  h \rvert$.

So the square root makes $\omega$ easier to compare to these other effect sizes, without resorting to a calculator or a computer (even if with the ubiquity of computers and calculators, this is certainly less of a concern today than it was in 1977).

You can convert $g$ to $\omega$ with the formula $\omega = 2 \times \lvert g \rvert$ (where the two expected proportions are 0.5 when calculating $\omega$). Here is an example in R:

```
library(rcompanion)
p = 0.3
g = 0.5-p
w = cohenW(c(p, 1-p), p = c(0.5,0.5))
w == g*2
TRUE
```

And here the plot from a simulation showing the linear relationship between $\omega$ and $g$:

[image: Scatterplot showing the linear relationship between Cohen's omega and Cohen's g]

For the relationhip between Cohen's $\omega$ and Cohen's $h$, things are trickier, due to the arsine transformation used when calculating $h$ - as the relationship between a proportion and its arcsine transformation is not linear. However, in the specific case where you have a contingency table with proportions of interest which are close to each other or not too extreme, if you have $h$, you can get a rough estimation of $\omega$ through the relation $ \omega \approx 0.5\times \lvert h \rvert$. In other cases, the formula is less reliable (but it depends on the degree of precision you need).

Below are three examples in R, where the approximation works well when p1=0.7 and p2=0.3, and when p1=0.03 and p2=0.01, but is much less reliable with p1=0.41 and p2=0.01.

```
  library(pwr)
  #the two proportions p1 and p2 are not too extreme
  #so the approximation works well
  p1 = 0.7
  p2= 0.3
  h = ES.h(p1,p2)
  w = cohenW(rbind(c(p1,1-p1), c(p2,1-p2)))
  approx.w = abs(h)/2 #abs(h)/2 converts h to an approximation of w
  res = c(w, approx.w) 
  names(res) = c("real w", "approximation of w")
  print(res)
    real w     approximation of w 
  0.4000000       0.4115168 
  
  #Below, the proportions are extreme (0.03 and 0.01), 
  #but are close to each other. 
  #So the approximation still works well   
  p1 = 0.03
  p2= 0.01
  h = ES.h(p1,p2)
  w = cohenW(rbind(c(p1,1-p1), c(p2,1-p2)))
  approx.w = abs(h)/2 
  res = c(w, approx.w) 
  names(res) = c("real w", "approximation of w")
  print(res)
     real w     approximation of w 
  0.07143000       0.07391559 


  #Below, the proportion p2 is extreme (0.01), 
  #but isn't close to the other.
  #Consequently, the approximation is much less reliable
  p1 = 0.41
  p2= 0.01
  h = ES.h(p1,p2)
  w = cohenW(rbind(c(p1,1-p1), c(p2,1-p2)))
  approx.w = abs(h)/2
  res = c(w, approx.w) 
  names(res) = c("real w", "approximation of w")
  print(res)
    real w      approximation of w
  0.4910000       0.5947375
```

Below is the plot from a simulation showing the relationship between $\omega$ and $h$, for contingency tables that do not include too extreme proportions (0.3 < p1 < 0.7 and 0.3 < p2 < 0.7). The relationship is almost perfectly linear, so if you know $h$, you can approximate $\omega$ with $ \omega \approx 0.5\times \lvert h \rvert$:

[image: Scatterplot showing the (almost perfect) linear relationship between Cohen's omega and Cohen's h, when proportions of interest are not too extreme]

And below is a graph showing what happens if you include extreme proportions (0 < p < 1 ) in the simulation. You see that it's more difficult to approximate $\omega$ from $h$:

[image: Scatterplot showing the relationship between Cohen's omega and Cohen's h, when dealing with extreme proportions. Contrary to the previous plot, the line is far from being straight. There is a sort of "fat arc" in the middle of the plot, that clearly shows that it is less reliable to find omega from h.]

**Reference**

Cohen, J. (1988). *Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences* (2nd ed.). Hillsdale, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates, Publishers.

Comment: +1, Really excellent explanation.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Cohen himself notes, the definition of w has the same structure as the [$\chi^2$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test):

[image]

See "A Power Primer", Jacob Cohen, Psychological Bulletin [PsycARTICLES]; July 1992; 112, 1; PsycARTICLES, p.157

Moreover, as you can see he calls this effect size measure and the corresponding test a *chi-square* and uses it for goodness-of-fit tests. He consistently used this name in reference to Cohen's w measure in his works, e.g. see his book "Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences", Second Edition, p.215.

Thus, I believe that the square root has no particular meaning. For all intents and purposes this is a chi-square test, and chi-square critical values are used. The square root can be a matter of convenience or convention.

Comment: This doesn't seem to respond to the question (at best it seems like a comment) -- *why* would one use $w$ rather than $w^2$ to measure effect size? The name of the distribution that results may be peripherally interesting but is not directly relevant to that issue.

Comment: @Glen_b, the distribution is relevant because in Cohen's book he explicitly links his w to $\chi^2$-distribution, noting that the only difference is that he uses *relative* frequencies, i.e. proportions, not the counts. He doesn't explain why exactly he chose to take the root. So, this made me think: why don't we use $\chi$ test instead of the standard $\chi^2$ test?

Comment: 1. Effect size relates to the null being false (we're measuring how far from no effect it is in a particular sense), so we're dealing with a noncentral chi. 2. Because the formula relates to proportions, not counts, it's actually the square root of (the chi-squared statistic, divided by total-$n$), so it's a *scaled, noncentral chi*. ... but even if you were right there, naming the distribution doesn't get us any closer to why he chose that particular statistic. ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  Cohen's writing (e.g. his paper on effect size) seems to lay the choice at the feet of Neyman and Pearson but I don't yet see a clear indication of how that choice is down to them. One thing to note is that in the 2x2 his measure is really the $\phi$ statistic

Comment: Fair points. I'll look up his first paper on the subject for clues

Comment: Maybe the answer is as simple as that: by using $w$ instead of $w^2$ the values are considerably bigger, thus, easier to grasp and numerically more similar to other effect size measures such as $\phi$ or $r$.

Comment: @Joe yes I think it will probably come down to similarity to some other effect sizes in situations where they might be roughly comparable.